# How to handle login operation failure?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have a JUnit 5 class in my tests. I want to perform a one time login operation relevant to all tests, so I put it in the @beforeAll method.

What I have done so far ,is checking the returned value for the login operation - true or false, and I check it in each test case before I start.

```
private static boolean loginSuccess;

@BeforeAll
static void beforeAll() {
    loginSuccess = feedServices.login();
}

@Test
void myTest() {
    if(!loginSuccess){
        log.error("Failed to login");
        return;
    }
    ....
}
```

Is there a more correct solution for that?

Comment: You could just throw an appropriate exception in your beforeAll method, if the login does not succeed; no test will be executed then in case of failed login - which seems the correct thing, if you currently check the success in every method.

Comment: @juwil Thanks. So, you say that if I throw an exception from the beforeAll, the tests won't be executed? Should I catch it somewhere? where?

Comment: You should not catch the exception, since throwing it stops the execution of the test.  The test will then be ignored by junit, it does not fail. If you want to see the tests fail, you might set the flag loginSuccess in your beforeAll method and then have another (non static) method annotated with @BeforeEach. In this method you would then check the flag and, if it is false simply call fail().